# Picture rotation

Tags: feature-request, edits, images

Is there a way to quickly rotate a picture in the SE editor without saving it on disk and rotating it in some image tool and reuploading it?  E.g. consider the picture below, assume I would like to quickly rotate it 90 degrees and wanted to do it expressly in the editor without the drudgery of saving it on disk, is there a shortcut in the stack exchange "markup language"?

[image]

If this feature is not available, I would like to nominate it for implementation.

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the tool in the picture?

Comment: A micrometer...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253403/1256347

Answer (score 8):

There is no image editing available within Stack Exchange editor, and it's unlikely to be added. SE is for questions and answers. Rotating images... or cropping them... or denoising, or fixing the balance of white, or the exposure or contrast... is something rather different. It's better to do one thing well.

In fact, Stack Exchange doesn't have anything to do with user-submitted images. They get sent to imgur for storage, and SE keeps only the URL.

Now, imgur does have image editing capabilities. But to use them, one has to be logged in to imgur with the account under which the image was submitted... so that's not going to work, because the images are uploaded under SE corporate account (for good reasons).

Another thing one could imagine is having some markup that gets translated into a CSS transform... unlikely to happen, for reasons of browser support, stability of markup, etc.

Comment: but it would be easy for SE to implement an expansion to their markup language to take an image from imgur and rotate it 90 deg

Comment: Their implementation of MarkDown is moving toward [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/), and this would be a step backwards.

Answer (score 7):

While the integrated IMGUR uploaded in SE doesn't provide ways to manipulate the image, you can use an intermediate step via IMGUR itself (no account needed):.

1. Visit [IMGUR](http://imgur.com);
2. Click on "upload images":

   [image]
3. Choose between a host of different options:

   [image]
4. Check the "Edit" box for the image to be uploaded and "Start Upload":

   [image]
5. Choose from any of the editing options (including "Rotate"); then "Save" your image:

   [image]
6. On the right, find and copy the "Direct Link" for the image (typically `http://i.imgur.com/<imageURL>`):

   [image]
7. Use the integrated SE image uploaded and paste the image URL:

   [image]

   [image]
8. Remember to keep the Internet clean, and delete the uploaded image:

   [image]